# Laravel how to inverse relation output

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have the following tables:

```
products(id, name, price)
features(id, name)
feature_values(id, feature_id, value)
warehouse (id, location)
product_warhouse(id, product_id, warehouse_id, quantity)
```

I want to get the products of nearest warehouse of certain point(latitude, longitude), and I want the output to be as follow:

```
products : {
{id: ... 
name:...
price: .... 
features: {
id: ...
name: ...
feature_vaulues:
{
{...},
{...}
}
}
```

in other words: I want products with features of each product and feature values of each feature and that also belongs to that product.

now I have the following code:

```
                $products= Product::whereHas('warehouses', static function ($q) use ($req) {
        $q->where('warehouses.id', Warehouse::orderByDistance('location', new Point($req- >query('lat'), $req->query('lng')))->first()->id);
    })
        ->with('feature_values')
        ->with('feature_values.feature')
        ->paginate();
```

but what I want is feature, feature.feature_values that also belong to that product and not only belong to that feature alone.

How to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not have any direct relationship between products and features, you cannot make use of the Builder relationship method to get what you want to achieve, so my solution is make a mutator inside your `Product` model to get the list of `Feature` objects, like `getFeaturesWithFeatureValueAttribute()` or something. Then, inside your method, you can make your own object format for the `features` property later.

To use the method, you need to call it inside the `JsonResource` class. You can make one [like this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections), then inside the array you want to return, define what properties and values that you want to return. For the property `features`, you just need to set the value to this:

`$this->features_with_feature_value`,

or call the method directly like this:

`$this->getFeaturesWithFeatureValueAttribute()` (I personally recommend you to take this option to prevent confusion in the future).

After that, you can use the `JsonResource` class for returning the data from the controller like the documentation mentioned. Don't worry, works well with the pagination as well! Hope this helps.